# In PHP, how can I create and add to an object?

Tags: php, arrays, object

Just so you know I'm working in WordPress. I have an array and want to create an object with only certain values from that array.

Then I have another separate array, I'd like to add to this new object. I might be over complicating things. If I am, please let me know.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$custom = get_post_custom(); //Gets array of values
$picObject = (object)$custom; //Creates object
$picCount = $custom['picturecount'][0];
for ($x = 1; $x <= $picCount; $x++) {
     // This assembles a URL that I want to add to the array. 
     $finalUrl = $picUrl.$gsi.'&picfilename='.$vin.'_00'.$x.'.jpg';
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else.  Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: `array_push($arr, $val)`. Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: You should show us what `$custom` looks like and what you expect your final output to be

Comment: Could you just work with arrays? It's not wrong to want to use an object, but is it necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an object with only **some** values from your array, you shouldn't cast the array because you'll end up with **all** of its values. Instead, create a new object and set the values you want:

```
$array = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'bar' => 'baz'
);

$object = new stdClass();

$object->bar = $array['bar'];
$object->something_else = 'w00t!';
```

Casting an array to object (i.e. `(object)$array`) will get you the same type of object, so you can still use `$object->new_property = 'foo';` to add stuff to it.

Comment: this is a pretty primitive way to handle this tho. I mean, it's barely an answer besides how to imperatively construct a new empty object.

Comment: Isn't that what he's asking though? To me, his question can be summarised as "how do I create an object from an array, and how do I add something to it?"

Comment: Exactly @rickdenhaan.